# completely remove kingroot when I can't find it

Tags: uninstallation

I installed kingroot and tried it, I closed it thinking it finished and rebooted my phone.

After reboot root checker says I have su binary but not root access.

My problem is I can't find kingroot, not in launcher nor in Settings->apps it doesn't appear anywhere yet when I install it from apk it doesn't say "Install" but "Replace", I tap on replace and wait until it says "application install failed".

I want to remove it completely But I don't find it , how do I uninstall it ? and if I can't find it then how the packaging tool detects it's installed ?

my phone is sony xperia P with android 4.0.4.

### EDIT :

I have found Kinguser.apk in /system/app not /data/app so That's why I can't find kingroot, it installs itself as system app(and apparently sets some permissions to not allow me to even see it)

So I need root to uninstall it, unfortunatly when I try su in terminal I get this :

`[-] Connection to ui timed out.`

So what to do?

### EDIT 2

Ok after I rebooted I can find kingroot in my Settings->apps->all now for some reason, I can disable it but not remove it (because As I said it has installed itself as system app).

Comment: Can you flash a custom recovery or do you have one? It would be easy to remove Kingroot using a custom recovery.

Comment: @Firelord I don't have custom recovery, is it a ROM ? if it is then I can't flash it as that needs root(right?) and I can't root.

Comment: You can use ES File Explorer to delete it from the system/apps  folder. Then goto android settings and remove it from the device administrators. Now you can uninstall it

Comment: I have to factory reset to remove the MALWARE kingroot and kinguser.

Answer (score 2):

Install kingroot again restart your phone, install system app remover application and use it to uninstall kingroot. [remover](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jumobile.manager.systemapp&hl=en)

Comment: I can't install it again, As I said in my post it refuses to install

Comment: OP wrote: "*root checker says I have su binary but not root access*". If root privilege cannot be gained then I don't think the app you linked would prove to be helpful.

Comment: which file explorer are you using

Comment: @Frrank file expert 6, why do you need this info ?!!! if you want me to manually uninstall it then I'm afraid I can't because it needs root access which I can't gain

Answer (score 0):

Try attempting to use different uninstaller apps to locate and remove the application.

KingRoot is a system app, so you will need a system app uninstaller, such as Jumobile System App Remover (which worked for me).

Try using a different launcher (this sounds weird, but in my experience some apps bind to launchers in strange ways...)

Try using a different rooting app, if possible, and going from there.

If none of these work, more drastic action might be needed.

Comment: whatever uninstaller there is I must have root access because kingroot is considered a system app and I can't gain root

Comment: I might try different rooting app but after I completly remove kingroot as I think whatever that app is kingroot will interfere with it

Comment: If only I can "su" like I do in my arch linux then I can do whatever I want

Comment: You might just have to reflash a stock firmware. I know this doesn't sound ideal, but if this is something you really need done, that might be the only way to do it.

Answer (score -1):

Solved the same problem. You said you have disabled it. Just ENABLE it back!!! And you have root access again!

Comment: thanks, I have solved the problem long ago by flashing the rom, I didn't post that as an answer because technically I was looking for solutions other than "format" so technically this isn't an answer